# How to deal with TypeError: must be str, not float

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to run this

```
 pa['pattern'] = pa['AccessType']  + pa.groupby(['AccessedBy'])['AccessType'].shift(1)
```

but it's throwing

```
  TypeError: must be str, not float
```

But

```
AccessedBy                 object
AccessType                 object
```

It was running fine when I last run it few days back. what am I missing ?

Comment: What is our goal with this?

Comment: The most specific advice I could give is to wrap it in str()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're data might have changed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['X']*4+['Z']*4, 'AccessType':[*'ABCDEFGH']})

df['AccessType'] + df.groupby('Group')['AccessType'].shift(1)
```

Runs fine:

```
0    NaN
1     BA
2     CB
3     DC
4    NaN
5     FE
6     GF
7     HG
Name: AccessType, dtype: object
```

However, you have to deal with those NaN.

But, if we change 'A' to a numerical 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group':['X']*4+['Z']*4, 'AccessType':[1]+[*'BCDEFGH']})

df['AccessType'] + df.groupby('Group')['AccessType'].shift(1)
```

You get:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Answer (score 1):

Convert one of the column in your DataFrame that you use as parameter to `str` by typecasting it before you do the `groupby()`.

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].astype(str)
```